# Importing Kmz files in a database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, kmz

I've a set of kmz files of point location. These point locations have 2 fields along with location. I want to import these kmz files in a free database. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Please take the [Tour] which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. Questions are expected to demonstrate effort toward solving the problem. There are at least a dozen different ways to achieve your goal; please [Edit] the question to specify what software you have chosen, what you have tried, and what error you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

easiest is probably to open them in Qgis and import to PostGIS using db-manager.

Or you can use ogr2ogr, a command line tool.